# Find the coordinates of the two stationary points of the curve defined by the equation $9x^2-6xy+4y^2=3$

Tags: calculus

A curve is defined the equation

$$9x^2-6xy+4y^2=3$$

Find the coordinates of the two stationary points.

\begin{align}
9x^2-6xy+4y^2 & = 3 \\
18x-6x\frac{dy}{dx}-6y+8y\frac{dy}{dx} & = 0 \\ 
\frac{dy}{dx}(8y-6x) & = 6y-18x \\
\frac{dy}{dx} & = \frac{(6y-18x)}{(8y-6x)} \\ 
\end{align}

Stationary points when $$\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

\begin{align}
\frac{(6y-18x)}{(8y-6x)} & = 0 \\
6y-18x & = 0 \\ 
y & = 3x \\ 
\end{align}

The $y$ coordinate of the stationary point is equal to $3x$ therefore I can substitute this value of $y$ into the original equation  and solve the quadratic.

\begin{align}
9x^2-6x(3x)+4(3x)^2 & = 3 \\
9x^2-18x^2+12x^2 & = 3 \\ 
3x^2 & = 3 \\ 
x & = \pm1 \\ 
\end{align}

Substituting both values of $x$ into the curve gives two quadratics in terms of $y$ without roots. The same thing happens if I use the fact that the $x$ coordinate of the stationary point if equal to $\frac{1}{3}y$.

How can I isolate a variable?

Comment: I'm voting to close this post as off-topic because it doesn't ask a question. ​ ​

Comment: How can I isolate a variable

Comment: Please tell us what your question actually is; isolate what variable?

Comment: $x$ or $y$, I can't answer the question without doing this

Comment: You incorrectly simplify $4(3x)^2$ after substituting $y=3x$.

Comment: With all due respect, if I could ask the correct question then I would understand how to solve the problem... would I not? Is it not obvious that I'm looking for the method used to solve the problem?

Comment: @Ethan Hunt I'll try this, thanks

Comment: After you correct your arithmetic error to obtain $ \ 27 x^2 \ = \ 3 \ \Rightarrow \ x \ = \ \pm \frac{1}{3} \ $ , you do not insert this into your _curve_ equation, but rather into the relation you found between the coordinates of "stationary points" , $ \ y \ = \ 3x \ $ .  The curve equation is that of a "tilted" ellipse and the line $ \ y \ = \ 3x \ $ indeed passes through the two points on that ellipse with "horizontal tangents".

Answer (score 1):

After you get $y = 3x$,

$9x^2-6x(3x)+4(3x)^2 = 3$

$9x^2 -18x^2 + 4(9x^2) = 3$

$27x^2 = 3$

which is very easily solvable.

Answer (score 0):

divide by 4: 
$ y^2 -\frac{3}{2}xy+\frac{9}{4}x^2 = \frac{3}{4}$
rearrange: $ ( y -\frac{3}{4}x)^2 + \frac{27}{16}x^2 = \frac{3}{4} $

bring on the other side, take square root and you get: $ y = \pm \sqrt{\frac{3}{4} - \frac{27}{16}x^2}+\frac{3}{4}x $

Check my calculation, however you should use the technique of completing the square

Comment: Your rearrangement in the first line does not equal the original equation.

Comment: This does not help OP answer the question

Comment: yes, he said that he wanted to isolate the variable, this is isolating the variable!

Comment: @EthanHunt , yeah I put a square where I shouldn't have, thanks. Now it's correct

Answer (score 0):

deepak's solution first solves for x, then y.
but i solve for y first, then x.
$y=3x$
$x=\frac{y}{3}$
$9(\frac{y}{3})^2-6(\frac{y}{3})y+4y^2=3$
$y^2-2y^2+4y^2=3$
$3y^2=3$
$y^2=1$
$y=\pm 1$
so the 2 points are $(x,y)=(1/3,1)$ and $(-1/3,-1)$

finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and setting it to 0 gives one more eqn. then we solve the pair of simultaneous eqns to find (x,y).